# System.IndexOutOfRangeException: “Индекс находился вне границ массива

Tags: c#, .net

Программисты, помогите!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace LearnEnglish
{
    public partial class Start : Form
    {

        public string[] WordsAndTranslate = new string[] { };
        public int[] OddNumbers = new int[] { };
        public int[] EvenNumbers = new int[] { };
        public int Count = 0;
        public int ButtonClick = 0;

        public Start()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void Start_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Words words = new Words();
            string Text = words.Get();
            string[] SplitText = Text.Split(',');
            while (true)
            {
                if(Count == SplitText.Length)
                {
                    break;
                }

                WordsAndTranslate = SplitText[Count].Split('-');
                Count++;
            }

            label1.Text = WordsAndTranslate[0];

            int CountOfletter = WordsAndTranslate.Length;
            int CountOfForFirst = 0;
            int CountOfForSecond = 0;

            for (int i = 1; i <= WordsAndTranslate.Length; i += 2)
            {
                OddNumbers[CountOfForFirst] = i;
                CountOfForFirst++;
            }
            for(int y = 0; y <= WordsAndTranslate.Length; y += 2)
            {
                EvenNumbers[CountOfForSecond] = y;
                CountOfForSecond++;
            }
        }

        private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(textBox1.Text == WordsAndTranslate[EvenNumbers[ButtonClick]]){
                label1.Text = WordsAndTranslate[OddNumbers[ButtonClick]];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Проблема:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= WordsAndTranslate.Length; i += 2)
{
    OddNumbers[CountOfForFirst] = i;
    CountOfForFirst++;
}
```

Comment: чо это ? `WordsAndTranslate` это? `EvenNumbers` Это? `CountOfForFirst` это? `CountOfForSecond`. Попробуйте обхяснить вот такой код `X = X[M]-Y[C]+A[F]` - вот такой же код вы нам скинули.

Comment: что это, дубль? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1031517/179763

Comment: Да, это дубль, так как я не умею выделять код в комментариях

Comment: а, так вы же можете добавлять всю нужную информацию прямо в ваш вопрос - вы можете менять текст вашего вопроса.

Comment: Я просто новенький на этом сайте, обычно все решения и так находил, а щас решил впервые попробовать зарегаться написать вопрос, чтоб не просто копипастить а понять суть проблемы

Comment: Никаких проблем, все мы учимся и все когда то начинали. По идее, нет смысла писать одинаковые вопросы несколько раз, потому выберете один, добавьте туда всю нужную информацию, а второй удалите.

Comment: Удалил старый, а сюда добавил всю инфу

Comment: Спасибо за понимание

Comment: Масив - это множество фиксированного размера. Вот тут `public int[] OddNumbers = new int[] { };` вы создаете пустой массив, то есть в нем нет места ничему, то есть например вы построили жилой дом без квартир. Поэтому, по какому бы индексу вы не обратились в это массиве, вы получите исключение, так как в построенном доме нет ни квартиры 0, ни квартиры 1, ни какой либо другой квартиры.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Помогаю:*

Массив `OddNumbers` не того размера, которого надо.

```
OddNumbers = new int[WordsAndTranslate.Length / 2 + WordsAndTranslate.Length % 2];
for (int i = 1; i <= WordsAndTranslate.Length; i += 2)
{
  ...
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99520/discussion-on-answer-by-igor-system-indexoutofrangeexception--).